# can i run a java software on startup

Tags: startup, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi with raspien installed. When I start my PI I would like to run the following steps after the operating system is loaded if possible:

1. a java software that checks the internet connection. If there was no connection a gui prompt to add internet properties should be shown and the user will then fill in a form to set the static ip and passwords as needed.
2. Now the PI has a connection and a browser should open with a given url.

It this possible?

Comment: Please add a comment on the downvote so I know that to improve

Comment: Why do you want a Java program (which we won't write for you)? This would normally be done with a few lines of shell script plus an existing tool such as Network Manager or WICD.

Comment: Doesn´t have to be Java but it´s the language I prefer. I will look into Network Manager and WICD. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can start any software (whether it is written in java or not) as an `autostart` task when starting your desktop session.

how this is actually done depends on the desktop environment you chose.

e.g. on LXDE you would add a `.desktop` file (e.g. `myapp.desktop`) to your `~/.config/autostart` directory (create one if not available) with 3 lines saying :

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Type=Application
Exec=java -jar /path/to/my/application.jar
```

the above information was found [here](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart).